# R dplyr join on range of dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to join two tables `xxx` and `yyy` using a composite unique key and date ranges. In sql I would simply specify in the join but I cannot get `dplyr` to work. Is this possible?

```
test<- inner_join(xxx, yyy, by = c("ID" = "ID",
                               "NRA"="NRA",
                               "date_low">"date",
                               "date_high"<"date"),
                               copy = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you provide input data and expected output?

Comment: Use `fuzzy_join` and then use `matches = c('=', '=', ">", "<")`

Comment: @user1357015 I cannot. The actual data is restricted. Example data is difficult to construct. `xxx.date_low` would almost always be lower than `yyy.date` which will almost always be higher than `xxx.date_high`. It's the functionality that I am after.

Comment: If you can't share this *exact* dataset, you can find a commonly available dataset that replicates the issue, or make up some data. Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it's difficult to do more than guess as to how to fix the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, thank you for trying to help me. I realize my question is incomplete. I moved away from `fuzzyjoin` because of all the `bioconductor` dependencies.

I used `sqldf` instead to accomplish the task:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT * FROM xxx
            LEFT JOIN yyy
            ON  xxx.ID  = yyy.ID
            AND xxx.NRA = yyy.NRA
            AND yyy.date BETWEEN xxx.date_low AND xxx.date_high")
```

The result is almost identical to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958975/join-tables-by-date-range) but I suspect it can also be solved with that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934361/merge-2-dataframes-if-value-within-range) as per Uwe's `data.table` solution.

I am also linking this [rstudio response](https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881)

Comment: probably an updated version of fuzzyjoin is powerjoin also in CRAN

Answer (score 8):

We could use `fuzzy_inner_join` from `fuzzy_join`

```
library(fuzzy_join)
fuzzy_inner_join(xxx, yyy,
              by = c("ID" = "ID",
                           "NRA"="NRA",
                           "date_low" =  "date",
                           "date_high" = "date"), 
              match_fun = list("==", "==", ">", "<"))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. I did just that and I got this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383510/r-passing-arguments-into-the-match-fun-function-in-fuzzyjoinfuzzy-join

Comment: @J.Doe.  Without a reproducible example, it is difficult.  The code is standard syntax

Comment: @akrun It seems some people have found that using backticks instead of quotes in the match_fun list will make it work.